# Google Play Console. Warning: You must add a physical address to your account details

Tags: android, console, google-play

Where i can put my physical address?

Since the new version of google play console, with the new interface, it seems to be more difficult to use it. There is no physical address section, maybe you can help me if you have encountered the same problem as me.

I put my addresses everywhere and it still doesnt work....

Comment: Did you find the solution? I have the same problem. I've checked everything and can't find where it thinks an address is missing.